# Symfony Form required true

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I have form and for field 'firstname' use required true, how override standard message - "please fill out this field"  ?

```
        $builder
        ->add('firstname', null, array('label' => 'First Name', 'max_length' => 255, 'required' => true))
```

In my entity field nullable  = true. If I want validate entity I know about      * @Assert\NotBlank(massage: "custom message"). But I 'required' => true only in form not entity (because need this for some api) And my question how change custom message if I validate field only in form

Comment: Are you talking about the HTML5 validation and that message is coming from the browser before you ever submit?  Is this part of an entity or is it a standalone form?

Comment: In my entity field nullable  = true. If I want validate entity I know about      * @Assert\NotBlank(massage: "custom message")/ But I 'required' => true only in form not entity (because need this for some api) And my question how change custom message if I validate field only in form

Answer (score 2):

To create custom symfony validation messages you need to create the `validation.yml` class inside `YourBundle/Resources/Config/validation.yml`

[image]

Then inside the validation

1. Set the entity of the form `YourBundle\Entity\EntityName`
2. The property on which you want to set the validation `properties:
       target:
           - NotBlank: { message: "Your custom message here" }`

Here is the screenshot of how I have setup my custom validation (ignore the constraint part for now, just check the properties section and how to set custom validation message.)

[image]

You might also want to turn off html5 validations by using **novalidate** while creating a form.

```
<form id="register-form" name="register-form" action="{{ path('register') }}" method="post" novalidate>
```

Comment: In my entity field nullable  = true. If I want validate entity I know about      * @Assert\NotBlank(massage: "custom message")/ But I 'required' => true only in form not entity (because need this for some api) And my question how change custom message if I validate field only in form